# Не работает SQL запрос

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sqlite

Использую SQLite в совокупности с WPF, C#

Имею несколько текстбоксов в программе, по значениям которых должна сортироваться и выводиться обратно в dataGrid таблица из БД

Код сортировки и вывода:

```
SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
try
{
    sqliteCon.Open();
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM '" + selectedTable + "' WHERE Откуда='" + FromTextBox.Text + "' AND Куда='" + ToWhereTextBox.Text + "' AND Курорт='" + ResortTextBox.Text + "' AND ВылетС='" + FlightFromTextBox.Text + "' AND ВылетПо='" + FlightUntillTextBox.Text + "' AND (Цена BETWEEN '" + Convert.ToInt32(PriceFromTextBox.Text) + "' AND '" + Convert.ToInt32(PriceUntillTextBox.Text) + "') AND Количество<='" + Convert.ToInt32(CountOfToursTextBox.Text) + "';";
    SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
    createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(createCommand);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(" '" + selectedTable + "' ");
    dataAdp.Fill(dt);
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    dataAdp.Update(dt);

    sqliteCon.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Пример входных данных из textbox'ов:

```
Москва
Турция
Шарм-Эль-Шейх
22/04/2015
01/04/2015
14000
45000
3
```

В таблице БД есть точно такая запись, но почему-то вывода не происходит, в datagrid ничего не отображается...
В чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Exeption не выдает

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery - не возвращает строк вроде, это для INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE запросов.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу sqlinjection и использовании параметризированных запросов согласна с другими отвечающими.

По поводу почему не работает запрос в вопросе. Большая вероятность, что проблема с форматами дат. Какой тип данных для полей в базе "ВылетС" и "ВылетПо"? Какой там настроен формат дат, хранится ли там еще и время? В текстовых полях задается английский формат, но неизвестно какой формат задан в базе. Если в поле базы еще задано время, то равенство в запросе использовать нельзя, только BETWEEN.

Если Вы не уверены. что форматы совпадают, то можно сделать запрос по датам универсальным, например, разделить в коде дату на ДД ММ ГГГГ и уже в запросе преобразовывать их в дату:

```
WHERE ВылетС = DATEFROMPARTS(ГГГГ,ММ,ДД)
```

Если в базе в поле даты еще хранится время (например, тип smalldatetime), то перед сравнением можно и его преобразовать только в дату:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ВылетС )  = DATEFROMPARTS(ГГГГ,ММ,ДД)
```

Comment: Спасибо, это очень полезная информация!

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте просто

```
SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, sqliteCon);
```

Промежуточную команду в вашем случае необязательно создавать.

Еще добавлю, что так как вы создаете запрос, его создавать нельзя. Такой способ создания неустойчив к sql injection. Нужно использовать команды с параметрами.

Comment: Хорошо, скорректировал, но, к сожалению, сортировки не происходит.

Comment: Нужно использовать команды с параметрами - можете, пожалуйста, кинуть ссылку почитать?

Comment: @Sergey_Yysmaa вот хорошая статья по sql injection, и в ней раздел Parameterised Queries http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev

Comment: А можете подсказать, почему именно мой код отказывается работать как нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Запись даты в таком виде `22/04/2015` не правильная, правильно было бы `2015/04/22`
Советую так же прочитать про Prepared Statements, при использовании такого подхода код будет нагляднее, и станет невозможным выполнение вредоносного кода со стороны клиента. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, все ответы были очень полезными, но я тривиально перепутал

```
Количество<='" + Convert.ToInt32(this.CountOfToursTextBox.Text) + "'"
```

c

```
Количество>='" + Convert.ToInt32(this.CountOfToursTextBox.Text) + "'"
```

Из-за этого, у меня вводимое значения билетов всегда неудовлитворяло условию...

Comment: Бывает :) Совет про sqlInjection не забудьте ;)